# Firebase Auth starts read/write in loop when opened in 2 tabs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, stripe-payments

I use firebase v9 with stripe for my web app. I retrieve custom claim with following code,

```
    const getStripeRole = async () => {
      await auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      const decodedToken = await auth.currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
      return decodedToken.claims.stripeRole || 'free'
    }
```

I use getIdToken(true) for force refresh. If I don't use it, it doesn't refresh when a user buys a subscription (even on refreshing the page).

When I open the web-app in 2 tabs and am signed in, it starts refreshing in loop and goes upto 12,000 reads & 12,000 writes in 30 minutes from just one terminal.

But if I don't use forceResfresh: true, I can't reflect the subscription change.

1. How should I implement this?
2. How to safeguard against such spikes/loops in read/write for firebase/firestore?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Firestore pricing has nothing to do with Firebase auth (the custom claims). The issues seems to be with Firestore queries. Can you share your code that seems to be the issue ?

Comment: I have added the code at start of question. if I remove true from getIdToken(true), it doesn't loop with web-app opened in 2 tabs. But then I can't update subscription status of the user on stripe payment. It loops when I open web-app in 2 tabs simultaneously. It works fine when opened in just one tab.